# How do I bash with a shield?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I bash with a shield in Skyrim?

My right mouse button puts up my shield, but I can't find a key or method of using it
to BASH an opponent. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Press the attack button *while* holding the shield button (on PC left click while holding right click). This will consume some stamina.

You must have either a shield or a bow equipped to bash.

Answer (score 4):

Raise your shield and then use the attack button to bash with your shield.

So <kbd>Right click</kbd> to **raise**, and <kbd>Left click</kbd> to **bash**.

Comment: Does that only work if I dont have a sword in my right hand ? I am thinking the left click will make me swing my sword.

Comment: @terry you should raise your shield so holding your right mouse click and than use your left mouse click to bash (this does consume stamina so if you got no stamina you won't be able to bash).

Answer (score 1):

While you block, your right hand switches to bash instead of whatever it was holding (spell, weapon, fist).  Just start blocking with your left hand, and then use your right hand to bash during the block.

You may block and block-bash with shield or twohanded weapons.

---

If you're using a bow, just use the left hand to bash with it (cannot block with a bow).

Answer (score 0):

On top of the normal bashing that the other answers mentioned.  You can also do a power bash with your shield by holding down the attack button.

There is also a unique shield Targe of the Blooded that some minor bleeding when you do a bash.

Comment: the power bash does need the talent tho.